# Is saying current as function of voltage same as current as function of $R$?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Is saying that current as a function of voltage same as saying current as voltage of Resistance?

And can we say both: current as function of voltage and resistance.

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on how you view it. A function is a map, while current is a physical quantity. It is a function only when you consider it as a map, which takes in an input and gives an output.

Take the Ohm's law as an example, $I = \frac{V}{R}$. You are free to consider it as a function of voltage, i.e. $I(V)$ takes in $V$ as the input and it outputs $I$, in this case you are treating $R$ as constant. You can also consider it as a function of resistance, $I(R)$, or even as a function of both, $I(V,R)$.

In the usual language, we write $f(x)$ to represent a function of $x$, but strictly speaking, it is actually not correct. Conceptually, we have to distinguish the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ from the value (output) $f(x)$ of the function at $x$. So in the case we discussed above, $I$ is the value of a function, but which function? It depends on your definition.